# A dead body (that eats and grows) in the basement

Tags: story-identification, books

This one is very old. I read it decades ago (edit: about 30 years ago) a short fantasy story that I want to read again, but I cannot find it using Google. The plot was:

- a married couple lives with a dead body in the basement of their house
- the body is the corpse of a former lover of the wife
- the husband killed him
- the dead body does not decay. Instead, it has to be fed, his nails have to be clipped, they have to cut his hair, and he even moans a little, but is otherwise still.
- they have to hide the corpse from the neighbors, they can't have visitors, etc.

Does anyone happen to know this one?

edit: It was a story on an anthology of fantasy stories, and I recall another one on that book: kids that discover psionic powers. But I'm afraid that's all I can remember about this.

Comment: Do you remember what language you read it in?